# Recently product view not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing a problem with showing the recently viewed products in my product page.

**Here is my local.xml code:** (I do not know why, but it is not showing all code, so i had to remove "<" from each tag- exmple- action, block etc...)

```
catalog_product_view translate="label">
    reference name="root">
      action method="setTemplate">page/1column.phtml
    
     
      block type="reports/product_viewed" name="product.recently.viewed" as="product_recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"/>
```

**Here is my footer.phtml code:**

```
    
    getUrl(''); 
          $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
          $url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($currentUrl);         
          if ($maniPage == $currentUrl){
            echo $this->takeCategory(12,1) /*12 = brands category 1 = show images*/ ;
          }
    ?> 
                                  
              getChildHtml('product_recently_viewed') ?>
```

**Here is my product_viewed.phtml** (standard file from core)

```
getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>

    
        __('Recently Viewed Products') ?>
    
    
        
        
            
                getProductUrl($_item) ?>">helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName() , 'name') ?>
            
        
        
        decorateList('recently-viewed-items');
```

When I inspect the elements, the `<div>` from the footer is empty.
All files posted are in my theme. I have my own css so may be it won't be shown as expected, but at least the div should have any data inside, right?
Could you please help me with this one.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your `<reference name="root">` is incorrect. Try changing it to `<reference name="footer">`, and verifying that is the correct reference.